# Necessito converter uma string em int dentro de uma hql

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Necessito mudar a string para int, porem ela se localiza dentro de uma hql, provavelmente terei que termina a query, mas ele da erro para entra no banco de dados, o meu codigo é um c# com asp.net, mvc, nhibernate.

```
public void soma(Rota post)
        {
        //* Tentativa de criação de query ja foi efetuada e não deu certo.
        string hql = "SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE Id=LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        //* Tentar converter o hql para int, para fazer comparação em if.
        int Km_Ultima = Convert.ToInt16(hql); 
        if (Km_Ultima <= p.Km_Atual)
```

Comment: Você já perguntou isso antes, né?

Comment: Qual erro amigo

Comment: De certo ponto sim, mas era o codigo inteiro e era uma outra pergunta

Comment: O erro que aparece é que "A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.", quando chamo esse paramento

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam É porque você tá tentando converter uma string `"SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE Id=LAST_INSERT_ID()"` em `short`. Isso não faz sentido. Você não deveria executar a _query_ antes?

Comment: Vou tentar, mas da outra vez falo que era um grupo de metodos e que não teria como converter

Answer (score 0):

Como o LINQ disse, você está tentando converter a string `"SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE Id=LAST_INSERT_ID()"` ao invés do valor que o banco de dados irá retornar.

Para fazer isso você terá que fazer um conexão ao banco de dados e executar o comando, para dai você converter o valor retornado e armazena-lo em uma variável.

Exemplo:

```
string hql = "SELECT Km_Atual FROM Rota WHERE Id=LAST_INSERT_ID()";
IQuery query = applicationSession.CreateQuery(hql).UniqueResult();
int Km_Ultima = int.Parse(query.ToString());

if (Km_Ultima <= p.Km_Atual)
```

Comment: O applicationSession ira fazer oque no código, é que ele esta mostrando erro e quero saber oque ira resultar.

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam qual erro?

Comment: `applicationSession` é a sessão com seu banco de dados ue. Coloquei esse nome só de exemplo. Para instanciar: `using (ISession applicationSession = MySQLSessionFactory.StartSession())`